# Retrieve other item properties too, after executing array.map

Tags: arrays, reactjs, properties, array.prototype.map

I am mapping a Data array to get My distance to the Points and I get as a result (null filtered, sorted array and then extracted) the Point with the nearest distance to Me. As a result I get "Distance: 234456".

Now I'm trying to do the same thing with a New/same Data array with one more property, and together with the map.distance result, I would get in return the extra property too.

The New Data array would have objects like `{id: "1", Point: "-34.910490, -56.201567", A: "4"}` so supposing this was going to be the nearest Point, I would get in return "Distance: 234456 and A: 4".

```
Data : [{id: "1", Point: "27.1597268, 40.6646601"},
        {id: "2", Point: "11.1640393, 49.6487153"},
        {id: "3", Point: "26.1539253, 42.6599287"}, 
        {id: "4", Point: "21.1597268, 44.6646601"}],


const distances = this.state.Data.map(
      (item) =>
        !!(coords.longitude && coords.latitude) &&
        getPreciseDistance(coords, item.Point)
    )
      .filter(Boolean)
      .sort()
      .map((distance) => <Text>{distance},</Text>);
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your issue, 
Do you mean that distances currently looks like this: `[234456, 394502, 3029305]`

but now you want it to be something like this: 
`[{distance: 39041, a: 4}, {distance: 312041, a: 6.6}, {distance: 930481, a: 59}]`
?

Comment: @Carolin just `[{distance: 234456, a: 4}]` is best (the closest Point)
But if all the array items come in, then I will pick the one I need, it's also good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make your function return an object with the properties `distance` and `a` you can change your map function to not only return a single value, but to return the object you want:

```
const distances = this.state.Data.map(
      (item) =>
        !!(coords.longitude && coords.latitude) &&
        // return an object instead of a single number
        ({ distance: getPreciseDistance(coords, item.Point), a: item.a})
    )
      .filter(Boolean)
      .sort()
```

However, if you are searching for a single item wit the largest distance, I would usually go with a [find function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) in the end of your function chain. This way you can be sure your function only returns one item at all times.

Comment: when I try to get the object with the two values I get "objects are not valid as a React child... {distance, a}

Comment: That is because now  distance is an object.
this means you can no longer do this: 
```
.map((distance) => <Text>{distance},</Text>);
```

but instead have to access the properties with the dot notation: 

```
.map((item) => <Text>{item.distance}, {item.a}</Text>);
```

Comment: at the moment your code expect a to exist on the items on the initial array. 
If that is not the case you will need your own logic to calculate a.